# How to build Microsoft Detours Express Version 3.0?

Tags: hook, detours

I'm trying to build detours library, and I encountered some problems that I did not succeeded to solve. 
I ran on Windows 7 and 10 64bit, Visual Studio 2015.

I tried in all possible command prompts( WOW64/ VS), ran vcvarsall.bat/vcvars32.bat.

Please find attached the errors that I've got.

[image: nmake example cmd]

Is there any other way to do it? or what could be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: There is zero need to post an image in this post. You can copy/paste text from the console. If you don't know how to do so, ask on [su]. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Detours Express only supports 32-bit processes, some of the files, such as `disolx64.cpp` and `disolarm.cpp`, cannot be compiled.

To work around the problem, try commenting the `#include "disasm.cpp"` directives in the `disol*.cpp` files that generate the fatal error messages (i.e. excepting `disolx86.cpp`). Then compile using `nmake` command.

Or better find and download `DetourExpress.msi`.