# How to Compile Detours Express 3.0

Tags: detours

Whenever I try to compile Detours Express 3.0 I always get the error code 0x2. I referred to this thread [How to build Microsoft Detours Express Version 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472960/how-to-build-microsoft-detours-express-version-3-0).

But my problem is still occurring.

Not exactly sure what's causing the problem I'm assuming it's because the DETOURS_TARGET_PROCESSOR is incorrect.

Log:

```
C:\Users\propg\Downloads\Detours Express Version 3.0 Build_339\Express\src>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.10.25019.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl /W3 /Zi /MTd /Gy /Gm- /Zl /Od /DDETOURS_BITS=32 /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x501 /Fd..\lib.X86\detours.pdb /Foobj.X86\ /c detours.cpp disasm.cpp disolx64.cpp disolia64.cpp disolarm.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.25019 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

detours.cpp
detours.cpp(319): fatal error C1189: #error:  Feature not supported in this release.
disasm.cpp
disasm.cpp(218): fatal error C1189: #error:  Feature not supported in this release.
disolx64.cpp
c:\users\propg\downloads\detours express version 3.0 build_339\express\src\disasm.cpp(218): fatal error C1189: #error:  Feature not supported in this release.
disolia64.cpp
c:\users\propg\downloads\detours express version 3.0 build_339\express\src\disasm.cpp(1566): fatal error C1189: #error:  Feature not supported in this release.
disolarm.cpp
c:\users\propg\downloads\detours express version 3.0 build_339\express\src\disasm.cpp(2235): fatal error C1189: #error:  Feature not supported in this release.
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Users\propg\Downloads\Detours Express Version 3.0 Build_339\Express\src>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472960/how-to-build-microsoft-detours-express-version-3-0
```

NMake File

```
    ##############################################################################
##
##  Makefile for Detours.
##
##  Microsoft Research Detours Package, Version 3.0 Build_339.
##
##  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
##

ROOT = ..
!include "$(ROOT)\system.mak"

!IF "$(DETOURS_SOURCE_BROWSING)" == ""
DETOURS_SOURCE_BROWSING = 0
!ENDIF

#######################/#######################################################
##
CFLAGS=/W3 /Zi /MTd /Gy /Gm- /Zl /Od /DDETOURS_BITS=$(DETOURS_BITS)

!IF $(DETOURS_SOURCE_BROWSING)==1
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) /FR
!ELSE
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x501
!ENDIF

!IF "$(DETOURS_TARGET_PROCESSOR)" == "IA64"
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) /wd4163 # intrinsic rdtebex not available; using newer Windows headers with older compiler
!ENDIF

!if defined(DETOURS_WIN_7) && defined(DETOURS_CL_17_OR_NEWER)
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) /D_USING_V110_SDK71_
!elseif defined(DETOURS_ANALYZE)
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) /analyze
!endif

OBJS = \
    $(OBJD)\detours.obj     \
    $(OBJD)\modules.obj     \
    $(OBJD)\disasm.obj      \
    $(OBJD)\image.obj       \
    $(OBJD)\creatwth.obj    \
    $(OBJD)\disolx86.obj    \
    $(OBJD)\disolx64.obj    \
    $(OBJD)\disolia64.obj   \
    $(OBJD)\disolarm.obj    \
    $(OBJD)\disolarm64.obj  \

##############################################################################
##
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .h .obj

!ifdef DETOURS_ANALYZE
.cpp{$(OBJD)}.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /Fd$(LIBD)\detours.pdb /Fo$(OBJD)\ /c $<
!else
.cpp{$(OBJD)}.obj::
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /Fd$(LIBD)\detours.pdb /Fo$(OBJD)\ /c $<
!endif

##############################################################################

all: dirs \
    $(LIBD)\detours.lib \
    $(INCD)\detours.h   \
    $(INCD)\detver.h    \
!IF $(DETOURS_SOURCE_BROWSING)==1
    $(OBJD)\detours.bsc \
!endif

##############################################################################

clean:
    -del *~ 2>nul
    -del $(LIBD)\detours.pdb $(LIBD)\detours.lib 2>nul
    -rmdir /q /s $(OBJD) 2>nul

realclean: clean
    -rmdir /q /s $(OBJDS) 2>nul

##############################################################################

dirs:
    @if not exist "$(INCD)" mkdir "$(INCD)" && echo.   Created $(INCD)
    @if not exist "$(LIBD)" mkdir "$(LIBD)" && echo.   Created $(LIBD)
    @if not exist "$(BIND)" mkdir "$(BIND)" && echo.   Created $(BIND)
    @if not exist "$(OBJD)" mkdir "$(OBJD)" && echo.   Created $(OBJD)

$(OBJD)\detours.bsc : $(OBJS)
    bscmake /v /n /o $@ $(OBJS:.obj=.sbr)

$(LIBD)\detours.lib : $(OBJS)
    link /lib /out:$@ $(OBJS)

$(INCD)\detours.h : detours.h
    copy detours.h $@

$(INCD)\detver.h : detver.h
    copy detver.h $@

$(OBJD)\detours.obj : detours.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\modules.obj : modules.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\disasm.obj : disasm.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\image.obj : image.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\creatwth.obj : creatwth.cpp uimports.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\disolx86.obj: disasm.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\disolx64.obj: disasm.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\disolia64.obj: disasm.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\disolarm.obj: disasm.cpp detours.h
$(OBJD)\disolarm64.obj: disasm.cpp detours.h

test: all
    cd $(MAKEDIR)\..\samples\slept
    nmake /nologo test
    cd $(MAKEDIR)

################################################################# End of File.
```

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 Community on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Detours Express only supports 32-bit processes. Comment the `#include "disasm.cpp"` directives in the disol*.cpp files that generate the fatal error messages excepting disolx86.cpp.